# Xpath to find an element using partial class name and exact text with capybara in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, xpath, capybara

I have html code with div having same matching text in class name as menu1 and text like

> Berlin

and

> Berlin Germany

for which when i use below code returns ambiguous elements

find(:xpath, "//div[contains(text(), \"Berlin\") and contains(@class, \"menu1\")]")

Note: I want both class and text to be in my xpath

Suggestions will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by partial class name you mean something like `<div class="blah menu1 other">Berlin</div>` then you could just do it in a readable way with something like

```
find('div.menu1', exact_text: 'Berlin')
```

or

```
find('div.menu1', text: 'Berlin', exact: true)
```

If it's more like `<div class="blah menu1_part other">Berlin</div>` you can still do it with a more readable CSS selector like

```
find('div[class*=menu1]', exact_text: 'Berlin')
```

If you actually need to do it all in one XPath for performance reasons (a LOT of `div.menu1` elements on the page, where you can't scope to a limited section of the page for some crazy reason) then you could do something like

```
find(:xpath, './/div[text()="Berlin"][contains(@class, "menu1")]')
```

Note the leading `.` in the XPath expression. 99.9% of the time when using Capybara, and manually writing your own XPath expressions, you want to start your XPath expressions with `.//`, otherwise you are defeating any scoping you have done - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap

Another option is to use the `xpath` gem Capybara uses internally for generating XPaths, which would be something like

```
find(:xpath, XPath.css('div.menu1')[XPath.string.n.is('Berlin')], exact: true)
```

or

```
find(:xpath, XPath.css('div[class *= "menu1"]')[XPath.string.n.is('Berlin')], exact: true)
```

depending on exactly what you mean by `partial class name`.  The benefit of doing something like that is the meaning of the `is` method can be changed from contains to equals depending on the value of the `exact` option, and it also handles all the normalizing and escaping of strings as necessary if your strings weren't as simple as 'Berlin'